# How to hide extjs grid columns names?

Tags: extjs

I have grid something like this:

```
Ext.define('Exp.view.dashboard.Tv', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
            {
                header: 'Actions',
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                items: [
                    {
                        icon   : '/images/icons/star_off.png'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I want hide *Name* and *Actions*. Maybe there is some undocumented config option to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In extjs 4, there is "hideHeaders" option. Set it to true.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-hideHeaders

Grid panel extends table panel, so it has this option.